# Does Android's (Lets say 4.0) WebView support WebGL?

Tags: android, webgl

I've been looking through the documentation and cannot find any mention of it, I know that the stock browser does not support WebGL and that Firefox for android does support WebGL, what I am wondering is if the WebView control (which you can use in APKs) supports WebGL.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

No, unless you have a specific Sony Ericsson phone.

http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wp/2011/02/24/webgl-support-in-the-android-web-browser/